# find vector involved in dot product when product and one vector is known

Tags: vectors

suppose we have $2$ vectors $a$ and $b$ ($a$ is known and $b$ is unknown) and we have the dot product of $a$ and $b$. Is there any method to find the vector $b$?

eg:

$$a=[3,1,2] \\
b=[i,j,k]\\
a\cdot b=5. $$

find $i$,$j$ and $k$.

Comment: There is **no unique** solution. $(1,0,1)$ or $(1,2,0)$ are examples. You have one equation with $3$ unknowns and normally get a $2$-dimensional solution space.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{equation}
\pmb{a}^{\text{T}} \pmb{b}  = 3i + j + 2k = 5
\end{equation}
This is an equation of 3 unknowns, therefore infinite number of solutions span 2 dimensions given as $\Big\lbrace (i,j,k) = (x,y,\frac{5-3x - y}{2})$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\Big\rbrace$.

Answer (score 1):

Solve the linear equation $3i+j+2k=5$. The set of solutions of a single linear equation in $\mathbf R^n$ is an affine space of codimension $1$.